# How to display files within sub directories

Tags: vb.net

My folder structure is as follows:

> abc/test/test2

I want to display file "test2".

I'm not getting error, but after execution the `ListView` is empty.

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub listViewBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lvErrorBtn.Click
    Dim TempStr(2) As String
    Dim TempNode As ListViewItem
    Dim intCount As Integer = 0
    'Clear listview
    lvError.Clear()
    'Add columns to listview
    lvError.Columns.Add("File Name", 250)
    lvError.Columns.Add("Date Modified", 100)
    lvError.Columns.Add("File Size in KB", 100)

    'taking path from appconfig file
    Dim appValue As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("errors").ToString()
    'going to the directory
    Dim dirInfo As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(appValue)
    Dim fsInfos() As FileInfo = dirInfo.GetFiles()
    Dim subdirs() As DirectoryInfo = dirInfo.GetDirectories()
    'iterating through subdir in directory
    For Each subdir As DirectoryInfo In subdirs
        'iterating through files in subdirectories
        For Each fsinfo As FileInfo In fsInfos
            If fromPDate.Value.Date <= fsinfo.LastAccessTime.Date Then
                TempStr(0) = fsinfo.ToString
                TempStr(1) = fsinfo.LastAccessTime
                TempStr(2) = Math.Round(fsinfo.Length / 1024)
                TempNode = New ListViewItem(TempStr)
                'add file to listview
                lvProcessed.Items.Add(TempNode)
                'count number of files in listview and display
                intCount += 1
                lvProcessedTxt.Text = intCount.ToString
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint and looking at the content of the variable? Which variable doesn't contain the information you are looking for? Maybe subdir is empty, we don't know.

Comment: This is a debugging question.  You have the data, set breakpoint and use the fabulous debugger to figure out whats not working right.  A DGV would make it all easier to do though

Comment: What is the value of `appValue`?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\IpSwitch\WS_FTPServer\wtfs1631.aus.us.siteprotect.com\users\abc\

Comment: If you want to look in the sub-subdirectories too, you will need to use the [DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories Method (String, SearchOption)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448(v=vs.110).aspx) with `SearchOption.AllDirectories`.

Comment: You must get the files of each `subdir` as well, not just the `fsInfos` array.